# How to edit choice list in multiple SharePoint lists

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way of programmatically changing a choice list in multiple SharePoint lists?

We have about 50 special SharePoint lists that are created from the same template. Is there a way of changing the choise list items in all these SharePoint lists ?

Thanks, 
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a c# answer, here is some sample code.  (It could be ported to PowerShell as well).  You could loop through any of your matching lists (based on name, template, or someone other method to retrieve the list of lists).  Then for each list, you could call a method like this:

```
private void updateChoiceFieldForOneList(SPList currentList, string fieldName, string[] arrayValues)
{
    SPFieldChoice choiceField = (SPFieldChoice) currentList.Fields[fieldName];
    choiceField.Choices.Clear();
    foreach (string oneValue in arrayValues)
    {
        choiceField.Choices.Add(oneValue);
    }
    choiceField.Update();       
}
```

You would call this with something like this:

```
updateChoiceFieldForOneList(currentWeb.GetList("/Lists/TestList"), "MyChoiceField", new string[] { "1", "2", "3" });
```